# How to refine build.xml file only for work execution app

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Inside maximo anywhere we have 4 apps out of which i want only work execution app to be build and deployed.

Currently ant build is building and deploying all apps which is time consuming. Please help

Answer (score 1):

It's in the build.properties for the solution.
Check [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.1/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.1/build_deploy/r_build_properties.html?lang=en) for some more info on it. The build.properties contains the variable aspects of the build process and defines the target server to which an app is deployed. it can be found here: maximoanywhere_home\AnywhereWorkManager

Comment: Thanks Kasey, its in build.properties where we can configure apps to build. That is already refined. But in maximo anywhere we have another file build.xml, which we can add to ant and run script to automate build. Currently its written to build all apps.

Answer (score 1):

In order to specify the applications you want to build, you're looking for "appsToBuild" property in build.properties as mentioned.

```
appsToBuild=WorkExecution
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to limit what apps are built, you will need to edit the "appsToBuild" property in the build.properties.

However, this does not apply to what apps are deployed. In my experience with Anywhere apps for iOS, all IPA files that are in the bin folder are deployed, not just the ones specified in the appsToBuild property in the build.properties file. This can cause problems (such as deploying an app that was not built for the server you are deploying to). To prevent this, delete the contents of the bin folder before running the all-dist command for the build ant script. Then when the all-deploy command is run, it will only deploy the files that were recently built to the server.

Comment: Additionally (and what I like to do to keep everything tidy) is run a build clean before a build on the server.

Comment: Is that the clean that is part of the ant build ant script? I think I've tried that in the past and it deleted files and never rebuilt them, breaking everything. Maybe I need to try that again (with a backup first!).

Comment: Yes, part of the ant script. If it didn't rebuild certain files than definitely reach out to IBM, as the only way to make this product better is letting them know of issues. One thing I learned quickly is what to back up and how to restore it. I have heavily customized the Work Execution application and have automated code migrations using Jenkins because we have such a quick development lifecycle.